# jQuery UI Tabs - IE 9.0 doesn't open links inside tab

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, user-interface, tabs

in INDEX.PHP my tabs are declared as:

```
$(function() {
            $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
                load: function(event, ui) {
                    console.log("load event ran");
                    $('a', ui.panel).live("click", function() {
                           $(ui.panel).load(this.href);
                           return false;
                           });
                   }

           });

        });
```

i have tabs linked to external php file to load content:

```
<div id="tabs">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="content.php?div=Production">Production</a></li>
              <li><a href="content.php?div=Digital">Digital</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

these do work!
but inside production content i have links:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="content.php?div=Production&p=add" class="tabLink">New product</a></li>
    <li><a href="content.php?div=Production&p=search" class="tabLink">Search</a></li>
</ul>
```

which calling the same content.php
content.php itself calling other files depending on GET criteria:

```
$div = htmlspecialchars(trim($_REQUEST["div"]));
$p = htmlspecialchars(strtolower($_GET["p"]));
$menu ='';
switch($div){
    case "Production":
        switch($p){
            case "add":
                include('Production/add.php');
                $menu = 'Production/production.php';
                break;
            case "search":
                include('Production/search.php');
                $menu = 'Production/production.php';
                break;
            default:
                include('Production/production.php');
        }
        break;
    case "Digital":
        switch($p){
/*          case "add":
                include('Production/add.php');
                break;
            case "search":
                include('Production/search.php');
                break; */
            default:
                echo "Nothing here yet";
        }
        break;
    default:
        echo "Please select department";
}
```

WHY IE doesn't keep within index.php, instead it actually goes to content.php?

Do i need to have a specific hack for IE for TABs declaration?
works perfectly in Chrome and Fireforx (as usual)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed this by using `live` and `redirect`

```
$(function() {

        $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
            load: function(event, ui) {
                $('a', ui.panel).live("click", function() {
                       $(ui.panel).load(this.href);
                       return false;
                       });
            }
       });
       $("#tabs").bind('tabsshow',function(event, ui) {
            window.location = ui.tab;
        })
    });
```